# Prove that $ f $ is a function

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

> $ \textbf{Question} $ (from Dudley's $ \textit{Real Analysis and Probability} $):
>
> Let $ E \subset X \times X $ be an equivalence relation on a set $ X $ and let $ \displaystyle f(x) := \{y \in X \; | \; yEx\} $ and $ f(y) = \{x \in X \; | \; xEy\}. $
>
> Prove that $ f $ is a function iff $ f(x) = f(y). $

For the only if part, since $ xEy = yEx, $ we must have $ \displaystyle f(x) = \{y \in X \; | \; yEx\} = f(y) = \{x \in X \; | \; xEy\}. $ So at this point the set $ f(x) $ and $ f(y) $ are equal, but I don't know why the theorem requires that $ f $ must be a function in this case.

Now for the if part, if $ f(x) = f(y), $ then $ \displaystyle \{y \in X \; | \; yEx\} = \{x \in X \; | \; xEy\}, $ but this certainly doesn't imply that $ f $ must be a function. For example, if $ f(x) = \{x, y, z \} $ for some $ y, z \in X $ such that $ zEx $ and $ yEx, $ then $ f(y) = \{y, x, z\}. $

I have no direction to go for this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The condition "iff $f(x) = f(y)$" is unclear.

Comment: $\forall x, xEx$ so $f(x) \ne \{y,z\}$ since $x$ must me in the set.

Comment: @avs He doesn't mention anything else explicitly about $ f(x), $ so I assume $ f(x) $ is the set of all elements $ y \in X $ such that $ yEx, $ the same applies for $ f(y). $

Comment: @DougM but what if $ f(x) = f(y) = \{x, y, z \}? $ In this case $ f $ is still not a function though

Comment: @PhucNguyen this was bothering me, too.  But if $S$ is the set of equivalence classes defined by $E$ then if we think of $f:X\to S$ it can indeed be a function.  Any $x$ can only belong to one equivalence class.

Comment: Phuc-- Your example doesn't show $f$ is not a function, only that its value at $x$ is same as its value at $y$, i.e. the function is not one-to-one. If $\{x,y,z\}$ is a complete equivalence class, then this just says each of $x,y,z$ map to that class. That doesn't make $f$ not a function.

Comment: $f(x)$ is the equivalence class of $x\in X$, say that $f$ is a function means that if $(x,y),(x,y')\in E$ then $y=y'$ and @avs is right. I can't understand this question.

Comment: I suspect something got garbled when you transcribed the exercise here. $f$ as you've defined it is *always* a function (since your definition assigns a definite value to $f(x)$ for each $x$), and the condition "iff $f(x) = f(y)$" makes no sense ($x$ and $y$ are unbound).

Comment: @PhucNguyen, in that case $f$ would be a function (if it were) from $X$ to where?

The way you have it, $f(x)$ is the equivalence class of $x$.  Such a mapping always maps the set $X$ (which is the domain of the equivalence relation) to the set of the equivalence classes, and it is always a surjective function.  It will be one-to-one if and only if each equivalence class contains only one element.  The wording you reproduce from the book doesn't look very instructive of meaninfgul.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @avs I guess I misunderstand the way he poses the question. And I think you're correct when you say $ f $ maps $ x $ to the equivalence class of $ x. $ In this case $ f $ is a function

Comment: I would learn the set theory you are learning from this book instead: https://books.google.com/books?id=cbbCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=equivalence&f=false

Comment: I think that $f\subset X\times S$ here where $S=\{\bar{x}: \bar{x}=\{y: yEx\}\}$. In that case $f$ would be a function iff $E$ is an equivalance relation.(Which might be the real question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact passage in the book is as follows:

> Given an equivalence relation $E$, an equivalence class is a set of the form $\{y\in X: yEx\}$ for any $x\in X$. It follows from the definition of equivalence relations that two equivalence classes are **either disjoint or identical**. Let $f(x):=\{y\in X: yEx\}$. Then $f$ is a function and $xEy$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$, so $E=E_f$, and every equivalence relation can be written in the form $E_f$.

Let me first introduce some new notation. I define $\bar{x}=\{y\in X: xEy\}$ where $x\in X$.

In this passage it is implied that $f\subset X\times S$ where $S=\{\bar{x}: x\in X, \}$.

So given any function $f\subset X\times Y$ we can form an equivalance relation $E\subset X\times X$ by defining $E=\{(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X: f(x_1)=f(x_2)\}$.

Vice verse given an equivalance relation E, we can form a function $f\subset X\times S$ by defining $f(x):= \bar{x}$. Clearly if $f(x)= \bar{x_1}$ and $f(x)=\bar{x_2}$ by equivalance $\bar{x_1}=\bar{x_2}$ so $f$ is indeed a function.

Note: Functions are seen in terms of relations in this chapter of the book so if you are given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x^2$. In this chapter $f$ would be instead rewritten as $f:=\{(x,x^2): x\in X\}$ or in general given $f:X\to Y$ we define $f$ to be $f:=\{(x,f(x)): x\in X, f(x)\in Y\}$.